# sed regex replace mobile number

Tags: regex, sed

I have a command:

```
echo '1-2 1-2? Is this mic on? Hello asd48300300300 48300300-asd 48300 world! It is 48300300300 asd ' | sed -E 's/48(.*)[:space:]/48500500500/g'
```

What I want is to just replace 48300300300 so it should look like:

```
1-2 1-2? Is this mic on? Hello asd48300300300 48300300-asd 48300 world! It is 48500500500 asd
```

The best option would something like this \s48[0-9]{9}\s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match a whole number starting with `48` and then having 9 digits:

```
sed -E 's/\<48[0-9]{9}\>/48500500500/'
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/wNK9Yl).

Output:

```
1-2 1-2? Is this mic on? Hello asd48300300300 48300300-asd 48300 world! It is 48500500500 asd
```

**Details**

- `\<` - a leading word boundary
- `48` - a literal substring
- `[0-9]{9}` - nine digits
- `\>` - a closing word boundary

The `\b` word boundaries may work, too: `sed -E 's/\b48[0-9]{9}\b/48500500500/'`.

If you must only match the number in between whitespaces use

```
sed -E 's/([[:space:]]|^)48[0-9]{9}([[:space:]]|$)/\148500500500\2/'
```

See [another online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/utAaot). Mind that the POSIX character class `[:space:]` must appear inside a bracket expression.

**Update based on the comments**

To add the last 3 digits from the number instead of hardcoding the last `500` you may use

```
sed -E 's/\<48[0-9]{6}([0-9]{3})\>/48500500\1/'
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/9PX05S).

Comment: Is there a way to also capture last three digits ? So:

1-2 1-2? Is this mic on? Hello asd48300300300 48300300-asd 48300 world! It is 48300300300 asd 

to:

1-2 1-2? Is this mic on? Hello asd48300300300 48300300-asd 48300 world! It is 48500500300 asd

Comment: Yes. What do you need to do with them?

Comment: Not sure  I see the difference :(

Comment: Replace 48300300300 to 48500500300 ? So we capture and append 300 from found number ?

Comment: Ok, use `sed -E 's/\<48[0-9]{6}([0-9]{3})\>/48500500\1/'`